# How to do preg_replace on a long string

Tags: preg-replace

I want to be able to find and replace a long line javascript code. The code has a lot / and \ in it too.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the limit manually so PHP will allow you to handle very long strings.
Put the following line somewhere before calling preg_replace.

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 99999999999);
```

Even better, if can modify your php.ini file, you can change the value of pcre.backtrack_limit  from there so the new limit will be globally available.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how long - there is an upper length limit (see http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php for how to detect if you reach it).

You can escape variables going into your pattern with preg_quote if you need to, which takes care of the / and \ characters.

Answer (score 1):

PHP string functions have size limit and sadly those limits are not specified...you will have to divide the whole sting into chunk of smaller strings ....then run [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) 
on each of the string..then combine those strings together..that is what I did.