# preg_replace doesn't work on local machine, works everywhere else

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code

```
$cities = preg_replace(
    '/^\\d*\\n(.*)\\n([^\\d].*|)/m',
    '\\item \\textbf{$1} -- $2',
    $_POST['cities']
);
```

`$_POST['cities']` [has this value](http://pastebin.com/SyLGfP3d).

`$cities` is identical to `$_POST['cities']` on my local machine and has had no replacements done.

I'm running PHP 5.5.9 through Xampp.

I've tested the code and regex through the following services, all telling me it should work:

[PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/alk)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hJ5vC6/1)

[Functions online (no direct link)](https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html)

`$count` is 0, so clearly it doesn't match, however above sources should be enough proof that it should.

**EDIT:** The code doesn't work on a much, much smaller string either (consisting of two matches).

Comment: Possible duplicate (no flag) of [How to do preg_replace on a long string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791015/how-to-do-preg-replace-on-a-long-string). Your XAMPP config might have a lower backtrack limit

Comment: @h2ooooooo It's not. I tried limiting the subject to only two matches and it still didn't work.

Comment: What's `var_dump(preg_last_error())`?

Comment: Does it match if you start simplifying your regex (I know this won't give you the result you're looking for).,

Comment: @h2ooooooo I changed the regex to `/^(.)(.*)/m` and it did indeed work. It seems to be an issue with my particular regex.

Comment: What are you trying to match? `\\d*` is equal to `a backslash followed by the character "d" matched 0 to infinity times` and will match (the literal) `\d` and `\dddddd` and `\dddddddddddddd`. Same with `\\n`. You might also be missing the unicode modifier (instead of `/m`, use `/mu`)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I'm pretty sure I have to double escape in PHP when using regex. Either way, I tried without the double escape and it still did not function. Please refer to my regex101 link.

Comment: As I mentioned, it might be your unicode. Try with the unicode modifier. And no, you don't have to escape the backslash in PHP regex unless you're matching a literal backslash or another special character (eg. `\.`).

Comment: @h2ooooooo The unicode modifier made no difference.

Comment: It's a good question. [According to 3v4l it works in all versions of PHP that they have installed](http://3v4l.org/CUCBC). Have you tried using the `php.ini` from a working installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was that my test server was running Windows and I was used to Regex on Linux. Windows matches newlines by `\r\n` instead of just `\n`, so I changed all `\n` to `\r?\n` for portability, which solved it.

**EDIT:** I am now using \R like suggested by [@je-suis-charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372239/je-suis-charlie).

I will accept this answer in two days.

Comment: You'd better to use `\R` that means `\n` or `\r\n`  or `\r`, it works on windows, linux and mac.